# Dynamic form not submitting

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am working on a dynamic registration form for an event with limited capacity, but I am having an issue where the form is not submitting under certain circumstances.  Allow me to explain...

One of the form fields asks the user to select the number of seats they would like to reserve.  The field is complemented with a counter that lists the number of available seats remaining.  The counter calculates the total number of seats occupied by totaling the relevant column from a MySQL database, then subtracting that number from the total number of seats available.  Here's how that looks...

```
<div id="seat_field">
    <select name="seats" id="seats" class="field" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>select</option>
        <option value="0">None</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>                    
    </select>                      
</div>

<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "***";
    $password = "***";
    $dbname = "***";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(seats) AS total_seats FROM event");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    $total_seats = $row['total_seats'];
    $available_seats = 44-$total_seats;

    echo "<div><div id='available_seats' class='seats'>$available_seats</div><div id='seats_remaining' class='seats'>&nbspseats remaining</div></div>";             
?>
```

When all of the seats are taken ($available_seats == 0), I replace the select element with a checkbox that allows a user to indicate whether or not their party should be added to a waitlist.  Here's the script, which is at the bottom of the body...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var available_seats = document.getElementById("available_seats").innerHTML;

    if (available_seats == 0){
        $("#seats").hide();
        $("#seats").prop('required', false);
        $("#seat_field").prepend("<strong>Check to add your party to the bus waiting list</strong>&nbsp&nbsp<input type='checkbox' name='waitlist' /> ");
    };
});
```

The select element is successfully hidden and the checkbox prepends.  However, the form does not submit... no console errors, nothing happens.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?  Thanks very much.

**Editing** - Adding the complete form...

```
<form action="volunteer.php" method="post" name="volunteer_form" id="plumb_form">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" class="field" id="first_name" required>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" class="field" id="last_name" required>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="field" id="email" required>

    <div id="seat_field">
    <select name="seats" id="seats" class="field" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>select</option>
        <option value="0">None</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>                    
    </select>                      
</div>

<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "***";
    $password = "***";
    $dbname = "***";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(seats) AS total_seats FROM event");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    $total_seats = $row['total_seats'];
    $available_seats = 44-$total_seats;

    echo "<div><div id='available_seats' class='seats'>$available_seats</div><div id='seats_remaining' class='seats'>&nbspseats remaining</div></div>";             
?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></p>

</form>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var available_seats = document.getElementById("available_seats").innerHTML;

    //THIS IS THE PART THAT'S CAUSING ME TROUBLE...
    if (available_seats == 0){
        $("#seat").hide();
        $("#seats").prop('required', false);
        $("#seat_field").prepend("<strong>Check to add your party to the bus waiting list</strong>&nbsp&nbsp<input type='checkbox' name='waitlist' value='1' /> ");
    };



    $("#plumb_form").submit(function() {

        var first_name = document.forms["plumb_form"]["first_name"].value;
        var last_name = document.forms["plumb_form"]["last_name"].value;
        var email = document.forms["plumb_form"]["email"].value;
        var seats = document.forms["plumb_form"]["seats"].value;


        if(first_name == "" || last_name == "" || email == "" || phone == "" || number == "" || seats == ""){
            return false;
        }


        else if (seats > available_seats) {
            alert("There are not enough seats remaining for your party. Please reduce the number of seats needed or email Darren at dklein@nycaudubon.org to place your party on a waiting list.");
            return false;
         }

        else{
            $("#submit").hide();
            //YOU CAN IGNORE THIS LAST LINE, JUST A LITTLE ANIMATION THING, NOT RELEVANT HERE
            $("#thing").append('<div id="submitting" class="buttonText animated flash">Submitting...</br><div class="againStop" id="stop">Please wait</div></div>');
        };
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: What is the role of jQuery here? It looks like it's not dynamic because the form is submitted directly, there's no AJAX. So it looks like the form is submitted successfully since the page content changed.

Comment: jQuery is not doing anything fancy, I just prefer it to Javascript in some situations.  There's no AJAX here - just a standard HTML form, dynamic in the sense that users will see a different form depending on the registration levels.  Basically, if all of the seats are taken, the seat select is hidden and a checkbox is added - however, the form stops submitting when the page loads under these circumstances.

Comment: Can you add the complete form HTML

Comment: Ok, appended to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who looked over this - I figured out that the culprit was in my form validation, though not as Konrad had mentioned (regardless, many thanks to Konrad for causing me to pay extra attention to the validation and thereby causing me to notice my actual mistake) -

```
if(first_name == "" || last_name == "" || email == "" || seats == ""){
    return false;
}
```

Under the circumstance when all seats are taken, I was forgetting to remove 'seats' from the validation, and so the form was returning false.

This is a pretty silly mistake, if I do say so myself... I got so hung up on the idea that this was some issue with the use of a conditional script swapping out elements based on the PHP/MySQL results that I totally overlooked the very simple solution that is now glaringly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is checking for a 'phone' and 'number' value, then returning false if not found. Those fields are not in your form. Remove that validation from the jQuery or add them as input fields to your form.

Comment: My bad - those are in the form but I left them out here in an attempt to prevent things from getting too busy, forgot to edit the validation to match.  Good catch, but unfortunately that's not what's causing the problem...

Comment: Since you're not getting any kind of errors from your submission, I still think the culprit is in that if statement because it's only returning false. Add an alert in there as well if only temporarily just to see if that's where you're getting stuck.

Comment: I figured it out - answer posted below.  It was a silly mistake and the problem was with the validation, though not the missing bits that you noticed.  Thanks for making me take a closer look, though.